# error C2664: 'send' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'ServerGreeting' to 'const char *'

Tags: c++, struct, c2664

I'm beginner on C++ and I'm porting a C code (TWAMP RFC5357) to a new project (IPSLA RFC 6812) and I facing this problem:

When I try to use the function *send*, I see the error "error C2664: 'send' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'ServerGreeting' to 'const char *'" "No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called".

So, I searched about this and I found some answers that I didn't understood.

Here is a  bit of the code:

```
    typedef struct server_greeting
    {
       UINT8 Unused[12]; 
       UINT32 Modes;
       UINT8 Challenge[16];
       UINT8 Salt[16];
       UINT32 Count; 
       UINT8 MBZ[12];
    } ServerGreeting;
```

`struct active_session {
    int socket;
  //  RequestSession req;
};

struct client_info {
    int socket;
    sockaddr_in addr;
    int sess_no;
    struct active_session sessions[MAX_SESSIONS_PER_CLIENT];
    timeval shutdown_time;
};

static void cleanup_client (struct client_info *client)
{
    fprintf (stderr,"Cleanup client %s\n", inet_ntoa(client->addr.sin_addr));
    FD_CLR(client->socket,&read_fds);
    closesocket(client->socket);
    used_sockets--;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < client->sess_no; i++)
        /* If socket is -1 the session has already been closed */
        if (client->sessions[i].socket > 0) {
            FD_CLR(client->sessions[i].socket, &read_fds);
            closesocket(client->sessions[i].socket);
            client->sessions[i].socket = -1;
            used_sockets--;
        }
    memset(client, 0, sizeof(struct client_info));
    //client->status = kOffline;
}


static int send_greeting(UINT8 mode_mask, struct client_info *client)
{
    int socket = client->socket;
    int i;
    ServerGreeting greet;
    memset(&greet, 0, sizeof(greet));
    greet.Modes = 1 & mode_mask;

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        greet.Challenge[i] = rand() % 16;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        greet.Salt[i] = rand() % 16;
    greet.Count = (1 << 12);

    int rv = send (socket, greet, sizeof(greet), 0);
    if (rv < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[%s] ", inet_ntoa(client->addr.sin_addr));
        perror("Failed to send ServerGreeting message");
        cleanup_client(client);
    } else {
        printf("Sent ServerGreeting message to %s. Result %d\n",
               inet_ntoa(client->addr.sin_addr), rv);
    }
    return rv;
}`

Could you help me with this? Thanks

Comment: I think the only option here is casting: `int rv = send (socket, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&greet), sizeof(greet), 0);`

Comment: Hey! I already change the code and it is working fine. I didn't know how I could use the reinterpret. So reinterpred_cast<const char*> solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: The user1320881 already help me. The solution was use reinterpret_cast.

Comment: The RFC you reference indicates that the structure your sending is expected to contain elements in network byte order (generally big-endian).  This means that if want your solution to be correct, you'll need to populate your greeting structure taking endian-ness into account.

Answer (score 1):

The [`send` function](http://linux.die.net/man/2/send) takes as its second parameter a `const char*` pointer to a buffer, so you'd need to pass in the address of your `struct` with an appropriate cast,

```
int rv = send (socket, (const char*)&greet, sizeof(greet), 0);
```

The compiler tells you that it cannot perform the conversion from the struct you're trying to pass to the type of pointer it expects, you should believe it.

Comment: vsoftco - The question was solved by the user1320881 where the suggest was the use of reinterpret_cast function. Thank you.

Comment: @vsoftco  This would be a much better answer, except that the original error message makes clear the argument type is `const char *`, so a cast is necessary. Although the OP doesn't say so explicitly I believe the context is Windows, where `send` has a less elegant definition: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Alan Stokes Ohh sorry I take it back... The issue is type of the pointer you pass, you are right. Thanks, edited the answer.